# Using join with two files fails on larger file sizes

Tags: text-processing, scripting, join

I am having some issues with a script that is using join to join two files. Eaxmple input files contains lines like this:

Here are the input file and the output of the join command:

```
D:\work\BuildScripts\3C>cat D:\temp\aaa.txt
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4_idd_module.cpp,83
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dencalmodule.cpp,73
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4denimagemodulerm.cpp,111
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4denimagemodulert.cpp,202
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityanqmodules.cpp,445
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityappl.cpp,378
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityappl.h,50
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityevrmodules.cpp,272
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.cpp,490
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.h,65
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecimgmodule.cpp,209
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecimgmodule.h,70
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecmodule.cpp,218
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecmodule.h,70
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dphimodules.cpp,610
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dphimodulesrt.cpp,115
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4rhomodulesrt.cpp,102

D:\work\BuildScripts\3C>cat D:\temp\bbb.txt
hzapplications\activect\ptc\ictsx01\ictsx01_bootuptask.cpp,1
hzapplications\activeps\iola\acquisition\iola_acqmodule.cpp,4
hzapplications\activeps\iola\simulation\iola_simmodule.cpp,3
hzapplications\activeps\iolr\simulation\iolr_simmodule.cpp,1
hzapplications\activeps\iolr\task\iolr_poweron200vhitask.cpp,1
hzapplications\activeps\iolr\task\iolr_poweron200vlowtask.cpp,1
hzapplications\activeps\iolr\task\iolr_poweronnrlvtask.cpp,1
hzapplications\activeps\iolr\task\iolrtaskcommon.cpp,2
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4equipment\adn4adseelem.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4equipment\adn4collar.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4equipment\adn4tool.cpp,2
hzapplications\adn\adn6c\adn6cequipment\adn6ccollar.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn8\adn8equipment\adn8tool.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn8\adn8neutron\adn8neutronkernel.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn8d\adn8ddensity\adn8ddensitykernel.cpp,1
hzapplications\adn\adn8d\adn8dequipment\adn8dtool.cpp,1

D:\work\BuildScripts\3C>join --ignore-case -1 1 -2 1 -t"," -o "1.1,1.2,2.2" -e "0" -a 1 D:\temp\aaa.txt D:\temp\bbb.txt
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4_idd_module.cpp,83,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dencalmodule.cpp,73,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4denimagemodulerm.cpp,111,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4denimagemodulert.cpp,202,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityanqmodules.cpp,445,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityappl.cpp,378,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityappl.h,50,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densityevrmodules.cpp,272,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.cpp,490,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.h,65,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecimgmodule.cpp,209,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecimgmodule.h,70,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecmodule.cpp,218,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitysecmodule.h,70,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dphimodules.cpp,610,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4dphimodulesrt.cpp,115,0
hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4rhomodulesrt.cpp,102,0

D:\work\BuildScripts\3C>
```

The expected output is that this particular line is joined like so:
    hzapplications\adn\adn4\adn4density\adn4densitykernel.cpp,490,1

Any suggests are most welcome. I am using the unxutils package on windows, this is the exact version:

```
D:\work\BuildScripts\3C>join --version
join (GNU textutils) 2.0
Written by Mike Haertel.

Copyright (C) 1999 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I've only skimmed this but... are your files sorted? join doesn't work if the input files aren't sorted on the join field.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the input files should be sorted, but to make double sure I have updated the test script to include a sort before doing the join.

Comment: This is a very old version of `join`, can you try a newer version?

Comment: That's not really sorting on the join field. You need `sort -t ',' -k 1,1` which could produce different results for some inputs. Recent versions of GNU coreutils have a `join --check-order` option that would help. It would be easier to see what's wrong if you just posted the actual `aaa` and `bbb` files for your failing test case. All the stuff leading up to their creation is irrelevant, boring, and not reproducible by us anyway.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for pointing me towards the correct sort command.  I have edited the question to add the raw input files and the output of the join command.

Comment: I just tried this on my macbook air and it works perfectly fine.  This must be an issue with the win32 port, but I'm not sure what my workaround will be.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. With the sample files I can reproduce the problem with a recent coreutils. It tells me that the files are not sorted, even though they look sorted to me. And I notice that getting rid of `--ignore-case` fixes it, but there aren't any uppercase letters in sight. Feels like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `--ignore-case` is the problem. It has an effect even when there are no uppercase letters because it treats all lowercase letters as uppercase, causing them to jump to the other side of the characters that are between the uppercase and lowercase in ASCII order: `[\]^_`

In normal sorted order, `iolrt` comes after `iolr_` but in `--ignore-case` order they are reversed.

The `sort` command needs the `-f` option to produce the correct order. (In addition to `-t,` and `-k1,1`)